# Преобразование XML с помощью XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Имеется XML-файл с такой структурой:

```
<main>
  <args>
    <fld>значение поля field</fld>
  </args>
</main>
```

Необходимо с помощью средств XSLT выполнить преобразование к такому виду:

```
<main>
  <args fld ="значение поля fld" >
</main>
```

Прошу вашей помощи, ибо самостоятельно выходит какая-то чепуха.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее просто это делается вот так:

```
<xsl:template match="args">
    <args fld="{fld}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Просто создаем элемент `args` с нужным списком атрибутов.

Если же по какой-то причине этот вариант не устраивает и требуется трансформация каждого поля в отдельности - нет никаких проблем. Единственное - нужно запретить обработку текстовых узлов внутри элемента args, иначе после их вывода атрибут добавить уже не получится:

```
<xsl:template match="args">
    <args>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </args>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="args/text()" />

<xsl:template match="args/fld">
    <xsl:attribute name="fld">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Для заранее неизвестного количества полей можно сделать вот так:

```
<xsl:template match="args/*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Если же у элемента args должны быть еще и обычные дети - придется исхитряться:

```
<xsl:template match="args">
  <args>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="attributes" />
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </args>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="attributes" />

<xsl:template match="args/fld" />
<xsl:template match="args/fld" mode="attributes">
  <xsl:attribute name="fld">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="args/child">
  <child>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </child>
</xsl:template>
```

Здесь обработка элемента args идет в два прохода. В первый проход собираются все атрибуты, во второй проход - все остальные дочерние узлы.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Возможно кому-то будет полезно

```
<xsl:template match="main">
        <main>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </main>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//fld">
   <xsl:element name="args">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Omg. `<args fld="{.}"/>` не работает что ли?

Comment: Не очень удачная идея создавать отдельный тэг args для каждого атрибута. Это решение не масштабируется для случая нескольких атрибутов.